# Link to another XML node in the same document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, pugixml

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Common>
    <Test name="B1">
        <Test id="100"><Name>a test</Name></Test>
        <Test id="101"><Name>another test</Name></Test>
    </Test>
    <Test name="B2">
        <Test id="500"><Name>a simple test</Name></Test>
        <Test id="501"><Name>another simple test</Name></Test>
    </Test>
    <Test name="B6">
        <!-- link to B2 to avoid redundancy -->
    </Test>
</Common>
```

I wanna link the content of `<Test name"B2">` to `<Test name="B6">` to avoid retyping the same data! (the different names are necessary) Which statement is needed to refer to this XML node? (pugixml should be able to parse it correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML does not support references of this sort. You can solve this with custom "syntax" and custom C++ code, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Common>
    <Test name="B1">
        <Test id="100"><Name>a test</Name></Test>
        <Test id="101"><Name>another test</Name></Test>
    </Test>
    <Test name="B2">
        <Test id="500"><Name>a simple test</Name></Test>
        <Test id="501"><Name>another simple test</Name></Test>
    </Test>
    <Test name="B6">
        <?link /Common/Test[@name='B2']?>
    </Test>
</Common>
```

Can be loaded with code like this:

```
bool resolve_links_rec(pugi::xml_node node)
{
    if (node.type() == pugi::node_pi && strcmp(node.name(), "link") == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            pugi::xml_node parent = node.parent();
            pugi::xpath_node_set ns = parent.select_nodes(node.value());

            for (size_t i = 0; i < ns.size(); ++i)
                parent.insert_copy_before(ns[i].node(), node);

            return true;
        }
        catch (pugi::xpath_exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error processing link " << node.path() << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (pugi::xml_node child = node.first_child(); child; )
        {
            pugi::xml_node next = child.next_sibling();

            if (resolve_links_rec(child))
                node.remove_child(child);

            child = next;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```